# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I am coping another function that was built in our site and tring to modify it to my preferences.

I am getting the following error and havent found a solution yet

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined      application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js:337
(anonymous function)                                                  application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js:337
Z.extend.each                                                         application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js:14
Z.fn.Z.each                                                           application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js:14
window.premlaneAnalysis                                               application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js:334
onload 23788:169
```

application-10ea3f5b8fa15aa9f943827f3d4ea7e2.js

```
318    function()
319     {
320         $(document).ready(function()
321             {
322                 return $("#prem_loads .pagination a").live("click",function()
323                     {
324                         var t,e;return t=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id"),
325                         $(this).html("<img src='/assets/ajax-loader3.gif' />"),
326                         this.href.indexOf(t)>0?$.getScript(this.href):(e=this.href,$.getScript(e.replace("searches","searches/"+t))),
327                         !1
328                     })
329             }),
330    window.premlaneAnalysis=function()
331             {
332                 var t;
333                 return $(".row-fluid").each(function()
334                     {
335                         var t;
336                         return t=$(this).children()[2],
337                         t.innerHTML="<img src='/assets/ajax-loader.gif' class='prem_results'/>"
338                     }),
339                 t=String(window.location),
340                 $.getScript(t.replace("searches","searches/prem_results")),
341                 !1
341             }
342     }.call(this),
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to JS myself, but it looks like this is a problem with variable scope. You have `t` defined in your first function, but its scope does not extend outside of it, so you're calling `.innerHTML()` on an undefined variable. Either define it again, or define it once outside of both functions.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins It has nothing do to with scope. `t` is declared in the callback, and assigned. The problem is that it is assigned `undefined` because the object referred by the return value of `$(this).children()` has no `2` property. Debugging would have showed that.

Comment: @PointedEars: Thanks. I've just started to make attempts at answers in the last couple days and it turns out to be as rich a learning experience as posting questions and getting answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeez, who writes code like this?

Ignore all the other nonsense, the problem code is this:

```
 $(".row-fluid").each(function()
                      {
                          var t;
                          return t=$(this).children()[2],
                             t.innerHTML="..."
                       });
```

This code is saying, set the inner-html of the third child of every element with the class "row-fluid".  The problem you are having is that one of those elements has fewer than three children.

Comment: Thanks that points me in the right direction. Just wish i knew more about javascript.  I made the script a little more readable.. it was all in 1 line with about 1000+ other scripts. all combined together.

Comment: Ah.  It had probably been run through a code compressor, which reduces its size and incidentally reduces its readability.